# How to write Console terminal with C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am studying for an exam and need your help.
I must write my own console terminal in C++, which must work in this way:

Example:

> :>`plus 5 7 "hit ENTER"`
>   :>`12`
>   :>`minus 10 12 "hit ENTER"`
>   :>`-2`
>   :>`combine Hello World "hit ENTER"`
>   :>`HelloWorld`
>   :>`run netstat "hit ENTER"`
>   :>`runs netstat`
>   :>`help`
>   :>`plus int1 int2` 
>   `minus int1 int2` 
>   `combine string1 string2` 
>   `run ?????` 
>   :>`exit` 
>   `program exits`

For main block I think it would be something like this

```
int main(void) {
    string x;
    while (true) {
        getline(cin, x);
        detect_command(x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The functions would be something like this

```
void my_plus(int a, int b) {
    cout << a + b;
}
void my_minus(int a, int b) {
    cout << a - b;
}
void my_combine(string a, string b) {
    ?????????????;
}
void my_run(?????????) {
    ???????????;
}
```

And the finally `detect_command`

```
void detect_command(string a) {
    const int arr_length = 10;
    string commands[arr_length] = { "plus", "minus", "help", "exit" };
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_length; i++) {
        if (a.compare(0, commands[i].length(), commands[i]) == 0) {
            ?????????????????????;
        }
    }

}
```

????? - means I don`t know what to write.

Help to make this program work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use the minus operation as an example...

Make a structure like so:

```
struct cmd_struct {
   const char *name;
   void (*func) (void *data);
};
```

Since your function parameters aren't the same, you gotta make a `struct`ure for each, e.g.:

```
struct minus_op {
   int rhs;
   int lhs;
};
```

And use the `cmd_struct` as an array, like so:

```
static cmd_struct commands[] = {
   { "minus", &my_minus },
    ...
};
```

my_minus would then be:

```
void my_minus(void *data) {
    struct minus_op *mop = data;
     ... do the computation and return ...
}
```

And loop through it to detect the command used:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(commands) / sizeof(commands[0]); ++i) {
   if (strcmp(commands[i].name, a) == 0) {
        ... prepare the data ...
        commands[i].func(data);
    }
}
```

Side Note: In order to get the function parameters from command line, have a splitter, e.g. a white space.  Use a vector for this and pass that vector to `detect_command`

Do also note: Get rid of the `void` param used in this example and use a `char **argv` and `int argc` like in main(). `argv` would be the arguments, and `argc` would be the number of arguments passed to the function. e.g. if you say to the program:

`>> minus 5 1`

Then `argc` should be 2 (the 5 and the 1) and argv[0] = "5" and argv[1] = "1".

Now that you know the idea behind it, implementing a more flexible version is left to you.

Comment: Thanks I got it. I`s finally works. https://codeo.me/2rN

Comment: then feel free to mark the answer that helped you the most as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Call a respective function to handle each word. For example:

```
enum commands {
  PLUS,
  MINUS,
  HELP,
  EXIT
  //....
};

int detect_command(string a) {
    const int arr_length = 10;
    string commands[arr_length] = { "plus", "minus", "help", "exit" };
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_length; i++) {
        if (a.compare(0, commands[i].length(), commands[i]) == 0)
         return i;    
    }
    return -1; //unknow word
}
```

Give the string to `detect_command()` the function return the respective integer to `enum commands` (that's our `i` value) or -1 if word is unknow. Then you can write a function like this to use and process the value determined by `detect_command()`:

```
void run_command(int cmd)
{
   switch(cmd) {
    case PLUS: run_plus(); break;
    case MINUS: run_minus(); break;
    // and so on to all comamnds available
   default: error("unknow command");
   }
}
```

each function `run_*()` should continues the command parsing according to own rules, i.e, the "plus" command should be follow by one integer, one white-space and then another integer, right? `run_plus()` must validate it and then compute the result. e.g.:

```
//pseudo code
void run_plus()
{
   //input here is one after "plus" word
   //here we must validate our valid input: two digits split by a white-spaces
  int x = parse_digit();
  check(white-space);
  int y = parse_digit();
  int r = x + y;
  display_result(r);
}
```

**NOTE:** I'm not a C++ programmer; I did `detect_command()` code modification to you get my idea. I even don't know if it will compile in C++ for the mismatch types.

Comment: Thanks for idea.  I`s finally works. https://codeo.me/2rN